# strange approach to showing menus

Tags: c

I am programming some device which has SDK.

Say I want to show some menu on display. You usually proceed like this:

```
void showSomeMenu()
{


...
drawItem(0, "menu option1");
drawItem(1, "menu option2");

while(1)
{
   key = getKey();
   if(key == KEY_ENTER)
   {
   showSomeOtherMenu();
   return; // or break
   }
}
...

}
```

You can see, if user clicks enter above, he can open `someOtherMenu`. Now say from that `someOtherMenu` user wants to go back. Then you implement it like this:

```
void showSomeOtherMenu()
{


...
// add menu items

while(1)
{
   key = getKey();
   if(key == KEY_ENTER)
   {
   showSomeMenu(); // Will open previous menu (implemented in the first snippet)
   return;
   }
}
...

}
```

What I find weird in this approach is that: say someone called `showSomeMenu`.
Then from that called `showSomeOtherMenu` by pressing Enter. Now from `showSomeOtherMenu` he clicked
Enter, which will again call `showSomeMenu` -- but **notice**, the first call to the `showSomeMenu` never had chance to return.

Even though this approach works and menus will be shown correctly, I am wondering maybe if this will end in a endless loop of functions calling each other. And maybe than I will have stack overflow issues or smth like that.

Am I right to worry? This approach to do it like this was shown in their samples. So I was thinking it should be the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you hit ENTER you will delve 1 step deeper into the stack, there is no way to return. This is [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) without a base case. Do not do it!

A simple fix would be to modify the code in `showSomeOtherMenu()` to 'go back' instead of recursing.

```
while(1) {
    key = getKey();
    if(key == KEY_ENTER) {
        return;
    }
    // handle other options here
}
```

A better approach is to keep a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) of menus that have been accessed. When you enter a menu you push it onto the stack, when you want to go back, you pop the stack and go to the menu that is then on the top of the stack.

e.g:

```
> Enter menu1      // stack is now [ menu1 ]<- head
> Enter menu2      // stack is now [ menu1, menu2 ]<- head
> Enter menu5      // stack is now [ menu1, menu2, menu5 ]<- head
> Back -> menu2    // stack is now [ menu1, menu2 ]<- head
> Enter menu4      // stack is now [ menu1, menu2, menu4 ]<- head
// etc.
```

An even better option is to use some kind of [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29), such that you only need one function to manage the menu. This is somewhat more complicated, but in essence you have a node for each menu, and a child of that node for each menu item. The nodes must have pointers to their parent node.

Comment: so you suggest to implement some kind of stack of menus myself? can you elaborate more?

Comment: I'd say go for the stack option. Use a basic linked list as a stack for menu IDs.

Comment: I don't have the time and comfort to code my own stack now :) but thanks for suggestion. I am just wondering now, if the "Pure" return approach that you suggested will work?

Comment: It will work, yes, you may need to move `drawItem()` and relevant code inside the `while(1)` loop though.

Comment: I was thinking exactly about that now, that I would have to move the `drawItem` code inside while loop otherwise, key pressing would work, but menu items would not display. Thanks for advice, I also think so far this approach will work ...

Comment: I am accepting your answer because indeed I think your suggestion with "Pure" returns is working! thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right to worry, this seems like horribly bad design.

In general it is much better to design things like this in a *data-driven* manner, i.e. with passive data structures that describe the hierarchy you want, then just a single function (`runMenu()` or something) that interprets the data and keeps track of the current menu and which "moves" are allowed.

Comment: Hi unwind, I see it's not a good design, but I am thinking about the solution now. Do you have some ideas? How to solve this problem? I don't think their sdk provides things as you mentioned; (having break instead of return doesn't help either right, I guess as in the code I put above)